# How to construct yql for "select count(DISTINCT user_id), count(*) from music group by gender"

Tags: vespa

I tried the following yql statement for

```
select count(DISTINCT user_id), count(*) from music group by gender


/search/?yql=select (…) | all(group(gender) each(output(count())                                                              
                              all(group(user_id) output(count()))));
```

and got an error:
"code": 5,
            "message": "Failed searching: Can not use output label 'count()' for multiple siblings.",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you want two different counts at the same level (documents and unique users).

This can usually be solved by unique labelling using "as", but unfortunately we require a matching each for label which doesn't account for this case. I'll create a GitHub issue for that. That said, you can achieve this by writing it as two parallel groupings with matching each'es:

```
all(all(group(gender) each(output(count())) as(documents))
    all(group(gender) each(group(user_id) output(count())) as(users)))
```